# access Menu in a private method

Tags: android, menuitem, layerdrawable

I'm adding a badge to an icon in `Toolbar`. I used `onCreateOptionMenu` to inflate the icon in toolbar. I need to used the Menu on a button click to use `LayerDrawable` for adding badge to the icon. I found that you can access Menu like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433550/how-can-we-use-menu-items-outside-onoptionitemselected-like-in-oncreate). But when I use Menu like this, the icon is not updated its recreated again in such way that there becomes 2 icons. One has a badge the other one does not. If I click on the button again, 3 icons are shown. Is there any way to do it properly?

```
public class ProdDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private MenuItem itemCart;
    private Menu menu;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_proddetails);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }   

    public void addcart(View view){
        updatecart();
    }

    public void updatecart(){
        //Getting current count frm database
        HashMap<String, String> pro = db.getCartCount();
        String count = pro.get("cartc");
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(count)) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart_menu, menu);
            MenuItem itemCart = menu.findItem(action_cart);
            LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();
            setBadgeCount(ProdDetailsActivity.this, icon, "1");
            db.addCart("1");
        } else {
            int cc = Integer.parseInt(count);
            String finalcount = String.valueOf(cc+1);
            Log.e("sammy_finalcount ",finalcount);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart_menu, menu);
            MenuItem itemCart = menu.findItem(action_cart);
            LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();
            setBadgeCount(ProdDetailsActivity.this, icon, finalcount);
            db.addCart(finalcount);
        }
    }

    public void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon, String count) {
        Log.e("sammy_count ",count);
        BadgeDrawable badge;
        Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge);
        if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
            badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
        } else {
            badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
        }

        badge.setCount(count);
        icon.mutate();
        icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updatecart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        //Accessing Menu here
        this.menu=menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart_menu, menu);

        MenuItem itemCart = menu.findItem(action_cart);
        LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();

        setBadgeCount(this,icon, "0");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }       
}
```

Comment: paste setBadgeCountMethod().

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: is the badge code working properly.Are you getting badge over icon.?

Comment: Yes but the icon is not updating, its generating another icon.

Comment: I resolved the error by removing the line `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart_menu, menu);` inside `updatecart()` method. But now the app crashes if I use `updatecart()` in `onresume`.

Comment: yo,it was getting inflated twice!

Comment: In LogCat, I get `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: remove menu.clear() from your onCreateOptionsMenu.It removes all items from the menu.

Comment: Still same error in `onResume`. Not getting **Menu** I think.

Comment: In your updateCart() method keep a check like this if(menu.findItem(action_cart) != null){// your remaining code}

Comment: Nevermind, instead of onResume, I'm now updating the code in `onCreateOptionMenu` itself.

Comment: It is not a good idea to update your code in onCreateOptionMenu.Keep your code clean and follow the standards.

Comment: I'm just adding badge to toolbar icon which I was doing earlier also. Now I'm getting the count from sqlite db instead. Its working good. The badge count is showing when I goto another activity and return back.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Yes, its working good.